# YouTube embedded iFrame API not starting new videos when playVideo() is called and the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have a webpage that plays continuous random videos (pulled from an external list), and it works great on mobile or desktop. But, when you try to chromecast the videos, the first one will successfully play on chromecast, but if my embedded player changes videos, it seems like the playVideo() function does not update what video is playing on the chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

In the process of writing the question I figured out I wasn't actually calling player.playVideo(), and was relying on the autoplay behavior of player.loadVideoById() in all other contexts. Adding a player.playVideo() call immediately after play.loadVideoById() fixed the issue!